# Can't use packages in GoClipse

Tags: go

I started learning go.
After my first try outs with the comand line, I installed Goclipse.
When I creating a new Go Project in this Enviroment I get to following
File Structure:
-bin
-pgk
   -windows_amd64
- src

Following this Example: http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/wiki/GettingStarted,
I created first a Hello World Program, here I havn't any Problems.

But when I create under the pkg folder an new folder clock and at the
file ampm.go I get the following Error in the first line:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - mkdir C:\Windows\go-build441906462: error 5 (FormatMessage failed with err=15100)
>   - 7 changed lines

When I try to Import the clock package in my hello.go File, I get the
error, that he cant find the package clock.

Comment: I am having the same sort of problem.  Has anyone posted (or could they write?!) an answer or blog post walking through these first steps?

Comment: Maybe it helps the install new newest Version of GoClipse, that has reduced many of my problems ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to manually compile things from the command line if you see errors in goclipse - I've noticed that sometimes it can't seem to recover from an error compiling a part of the program. You might also check the Go config in Eclipse if you've changed versions, since they moved files around. Cleaning the build and changing a file can force it to rebuild too.

The folder structure should be like this:

```
proj
--bin (for commands)
----os_architecture 
--pkg (for compiled packages)
----os_architecture 
--src
----pkg
------mypkgfolder
----cmd
```

You can compile a package or command like: `go build src/cmd/*.go`